# PHP glob and unlink

Tags: php, glob, unlink

a bit of a weird one, but I have figured out how to use glob to display a list of images, and now I want to add a button under each image that would let you delete each image individually, I think I just need to use unlink, but whenever I try it just seems to delete every file on the server!:')

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
  // This sets the variable $filelist, and get it to search the specificied levels of wildcards for jpg, png, JPG, and PNG using glob:
    $filelist = glob('{*.jpg,*/*.jpg,*/*/*.jpg,*/*/*/*.jpg,*/*/*/*/*.jpg,*/*/*/*/*/*.jpg,*.png,*/*.png,*/*/*.png,*/*/*/*.png,*/*/*/*/*.png,*/*/*/*/*/*.png,*.JPG,*/*.JPG,*/*/*.JPG,*/*/*/*.JPG,*/*/*/*/*.JPG,*/*/*/*/*/*.jpg,*.PNG,*/*.PNG,*/*/*.PNG,*/*/*/*.PNG,*/*/*/*/*.PNG,*/*/*/*/*/*.PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);

  // This filters the above into date order from newest to oldest:
  usort($filelist, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);'));

  // This is how I now output the data, basically looks for each value of $filelist and sets it as $link, then outputs this and concatenates it with itself as a href and a background-image:
  echo '<div class="thumbnail-grid">';

      if($filelist){
        foreach($filelist as $link){
          echo '<div class="tile-container">';
          echo '<a style="background-image: url('.$link.');" class="photo-link" href="'.$link.'"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></a>';
          // This adds in a delete button:
          echo '<form method="post"><input style="cursor: pointer;" name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE"></form>  ';
          echo '</div>';
          // This is the script that should be doing the unlinking:
          if(isset($_POST['delete']))
            {
                unlink($link);
            }
        }
      }else{
        echo ' No images found.';
      }

  echo '</div>';
```

Hope this all makes sense/isn't asking too much!

Many thanks, Jack.

Comment: Your submit button/form does not carry any information on which file to delete really. It's just a dozen buttons which all do the same, because `if(isset($_POST['delete']))` does and cannot possibly associate it to a specific loop entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't very secure as anyone can send a POST variable with a filename and delete it. 
 But as an example, you can loop through the files and give the delete button a value of the filename and then when you check for the posted delete button delete the file.

```
// This is the script that should be doing the unlinking:
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    unlink($_POST['delete']);
}

if($filelist){
    foreach($filelist as $link){
        echo '<div class="tile-container">';
        echo '<a style="background-image: url('.$link.');" class="photo-link" href="'.$link.'"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></a>';
        echo '<form method="post">
        <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="delete" type="submit" value="'.$link.'">
        </form> ';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}else{
    echo ' No images found.';
}
```

Comment: aha yeah it is pretty dodgy but its for a very specific use case so i'm not too bothered about security:-)  But thanks for that, that solution works a treat! I thought it must be something like that but I was setting the input name as $link, I didnt know you had to do it with the value itself. Thanks for your help:)